# How to merge two unsigned chars into a single unsigned short(16 bits) in c++

Tags: c++, bit, byte-shifting

How do I merge two unsigned chars into a single unsigned short in c++.
The Most Significant Byte in the array is contained in array[0] and the Least Significant Byte is located at array[1] . (Big endian)

Answer (score 3):

`(array[0] << 8) | array[1]`

Note that an `unsigned char` is implicitly converted ("promoted") to `int` when you use it for any calculations. Therefore `array[0] << 8` doesn't overflow. Also the result of this calculation is an `int`, so you may cast it back to unsigned short if your compiler issues a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Set the short to the least significant byte, shift the most significant byte by 8 and perform a binary or operation to keep the lower half

```
unsigned short s;
s = array[1];
s |= (unsigned short) array[0] << 8;
```